# GIMP failed to uninstall

Tags: package-management, uninstall, gimp

This is what I get when I try to uninstall GIMP:

```
yoyo@yoyo-Inspiron-3521:~$ sudo apt-get remove gimp 
[sudo] password for yoyo:  
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree     
Reading state information... Done 
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.19)  libc6:i386 :
Recommends: libc6-i686:i386
             Breaks: locales (< 2.19) 
             E: Unmet dependencies. 
Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).


> yoyo@yoyo-Inspiron-3521:~$ sudo apt-get install -f 
  Reading package lists... Done 
  Building dependency tree        
  Reading state information... Done 
  Correcting dependencies... Done 
  The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:  
> gcc-4.8-base:i386 libtiff-tools Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove
> them. The following extra packages will be installed:   
  locales 
  The following packages will be upgraded:   
   locales 
  1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1680 not upgraded.
  Need to get 0 B/3 924 kB of archives. 
  After this operation, 6 904 kB of additional disk space
> will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: did you try running `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: Yes ! and nothing good yet thanx

Comment: did it run successfully?

Comment: Does your system produce an error message when you run `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: yeah it gave me a couple of errors

Comment: @dirham22 please post that

Comment: OK bro.. let me add it that to the question

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues before and found aptitude fixes the problem:
`sudo apt-get install aptitude`
`sudo aptitude update`
`sudo aptitude upgrade`
Aptitude will give you a list of options to choose from to fix your system.

Comment: thanks bro but.. aptitude can't even install because of the same crap I'm trying to solve

Comment: ah damn, my mistake, sorry about that. can you try `sudo aptitude update` and `sudo aptitude upgrade`? If it's Ubuntu i'm pretty sure they're already installed. Just be very careful of anything involving remove. Also, what happens if you hit yes after your initial posting of `> will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n]`

Comment: Oh mk444, thank you brother but I've already done something promising. i unticked all third party software providers in the 'software and updates' app and the ran sudo apt-get update. it seems nice atleast for now